# VMware 16.1.0 PRO Machine worked before but now fails with "The firmware encountered an unexpected exception. The virtual machine cannot boot."

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, home-automation-x10

I am using Home Assistant virtual machine on Vmware for very long time. It always worked reliably. But now, suddenly, without any changes, it fails to boot with

> "The firmware encountered an unexpected exception. The virtual machine
> cannot boot."

See the screenshot:

[image: See screenshot]
I haven't changed anything, neither on host pc, neither on guest virtual machine. I tried following information from web saying that I should add this line to vmx file:

```
pciHole.dyn = "FALSE"
```

but nothing changes.

I have no idea what to do any more. How to unlock this vmware machine and furthermore? Why did it even fail, as I haven't changed anything?

*PS: Other vms are ok*

Comment: Update the Host BIOS and make sure VT-d Hardware Virtualization is (remains) enabled.  I am using VMware Pro V 16 newest here with no issue.

Comment: After the updates to correct firmware issues (Host) you still have an issue, make a new test build of the VM and see if it works.

Comment: @John I don't know what happened, but (yesterday) after few hours, without even restarting the PC, it suddenly started working again. I have no idea why. I will keep the question open in case that happens again. Very strange.